# Media queries with less and Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am just getting started with less. In an attempt to mmake less ugly Bootstrap's multitude of classes on tags, I have attempted to write some simple wrappers in less.

The entireity of my code is below.

```
// Import boostrap.
@import "./less/bootstrap.less";

// General classes for content.
focus {
    .span12;
}

content {
    .span8;
}

side {
    .span4;
}
```

The purpose of this less file is to provide nice looking wrappers that do a single thing, such as Bootstrap's `.span12` class. I will, in time, extend this to buttons of sorts.

Either way, I am running into a problem when compiling the less file using `lessc style.less`.

The error it gives is:

```
NameError: .span12 is undefined in /srv/http/www/style.less on line 6, column 5:
5 focus {
6     .span12;
7 }
```

I have found some documentation with the `.makeColumn(i)` class but the problem with that is Bootstrap already has perfectly good media queries and I wanted to avoid writing my own.

Is there anyway to wrap the classes that already have the media queries or do I need to just suck it up and write my own for my wrappers?

Comment: Are you sure your import is working? I've found that mine weren't always importing

Comment: @Kyle They were working. I know this because I changed the ".spanX" selectors to ones I knew would work and it compiled all of Bootstrap into a file. See the answer below though for why my approach didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are going to run into a few major problems in this approach.

First, there are issues in that Bootstrap is dynamically generating the `.spanX` series of classes, so they are not immediately accessible as mixins, [as I note in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552875/less-and-bootstrap-how-to-use-a-span3-or-spanx-any-number-class-as-a-mixin/15573240#15573240).

Second, some of Bootstrap's `span` code is not set by the `.spanX` series, but is done through an attribute selector of `[class*="span"]` ([see, as of this writing, line 602 of the mixins.less file](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less); they are also extensively used [in the responsive files for the `@media` rules](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less)). This selector code would not be picked up by a `.span12` inclusion of code, and if you are not putting `.span12` in your code, then your code will not have those properties applied. So you need to work around that.

There may be other issues not immediately obvious, but the point is, if you want to use Bootstrap for grid purposes (especially responsive), it is probably best to use it as it is designed. If you do not, then it is best to go and copy the Bootstrap code and modify it as you desire to make your own reduced grid code (if your intent is to use less overall classes in your html).

Comment: In the day between this answer and my question I did some research and I found that this is the case. I was considering forking bootstrap and just changing around some of the class names (I don't know if that would be that easy, but I thought about it!) to make it work how I want to.. But I am really not that concerned. I guess what I was looking for was a good semantic layout, having already looked at semantic.gs.. I may try again, but Bootstrap is just too darn easy to use.