# Why gives Grunt / Recess an error and Lessc not when compiling Bootstrap 3 RC1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs, twitter-recess

I add some code to mixins.less:

```
 img {   &:extend(.img-responsive); }
```

See also: [Images not responsive by default in Twitter Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932509/images-not-responsive-by-default-in-twitter-bootstrap-3-0-rc1/17933207) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573240/1596547

When i run `grunt dist` from the command line i got:

```
Running "recess:bootstrap" (recess) task
>> Parser error in less/mixins.less
>>      549. img {
>>      550.   &:extend(.img-responsive);
>>      551. }
Warning:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

But when i compile it with Lessc: `lessc bootstrap.less` i don't find an error. (lessc 1.4.2 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
)

`&:extend` needs Less 1.4.0. So grunt / recess use a different compiler?

**update**
running `install grunt-contrib-less --save-dev` gives:

```
grunt-contrib-less@0.7.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-less
├── grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1 (zlib-browserify@0.0.1)
└── less@1.4.2 (mime@1.2.11, mkdirp@0.3.5, ycssmin@1.0.1, request@2.27.0)
```

so i expect less v1.4.2 but still got this error

Comment: Same issue as yours right now. Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know. I run Bootstrap 3.1.1. at the moment. I only found this problem only for 3.0 RC1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of `grunt-contrib-less` you have.

Run:

```
npm update grunt-contrib-less
```

Comment: thank for your response. I tried but still got the same error

Comment: Your gruntfile is still referring to recess for how to compile the less.  That will need to be updated as well, or it will still use recess to compile.