# input cursor and text not appearing in input fields with Bootstrap version 3.1

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I just updated my portfolio site - (www.jaredmc.com) and used the Twitter Bootstrap framework. However in the first two form fields/inputs no cursor or text appears in Firefox (latest version). I've confirmed with testing that the data will submit even though it's not visible.  Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using FF to test? Also I'm on a Mac so I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: indeed - it's broken in FF. Haven't noticed you've specified it explicitly in the question.

Comment: http://biostall.com/firefox-not-displaying-placeholder-or-text-entered-into-textbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I learned that the "form-control" class in Bootstrap prevents the cursor and text from appearing b/c of default styles. Then I was able to research and find the following stackoverflow answer to answer my question - [How can I work around the need for Bootstrap 3's form-control class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158293/how-can-i-work-around-the-need-for-bootstrap-3s-form-control-class).