# Meteor 0.6.5.1 and twitter typeahead.js - (How) does it work?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I switched from Twitter Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3 and found myself without typeahead, it's recommended to use Twitter typeahead.js now. The corresponding [meteor package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/typeahead-js) seems to be up to date in terms of [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#features), but probably has been outdated by the latest updates of meteor. For me, it doesn't work correctly.

Does somebody know how to run typeahead.js in Meteor or confirm I'm just using it wrong?

From my code I get this messed up typahead formatting:

[image: messed up typeahead formatting]

Thanks for any hint!

**typeahead.html**

```
<head>
  <title>typeahead</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>
<template name="hello">
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="typeahead">
    </div>
</form>
</template>
```

**typeahead.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.rendered = function () {
    $('input#typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'accounts',
        local: ['timtrueman', 'JakeHarding', 'vskarich']
        });
  };
}
```

Comment: check this pull request https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/393 with questions  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167246/typeahead-problems-with-bootstrap-3-0-rc1/18171568 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059161/css-issue-on-twitter-typeahead-with-bootstrap-3 seems to be the same problem. You could also consider to use: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Comment: thanks for the hints, and very much for creating the b3-typeahead-plugin, I am checking it out!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18171568/1691147

In regards to how to do it in meteor. In your rendered function, fill up typeahead

```
    var items = [],
finalItems,
tags = Tags.find({}, {fields: {name: 1, submitted: 0}});
tags.forEach(function(tag){
    items.push(tag.name);
});
finalItems = _.uniq(items)
$('#search').typeahead({
    local: finalItems
});
```

Then, on a keyup event, do

```
   $('.tt-query').css('background-color','#fff');
   $('#search').removeClass('tt-query');
```

And in your css, add

```
.twitter-typeahead{
width:100%;
}

.twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 160px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}

.tt-suggestion {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0)
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor a {
  color: #fff;
}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

It's pretty hacky, but it will work until they get Typeahead and Bootstrap 3 to play nicely with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after general free-text autocomplete, you may want to check out my autocomplete package for meteor, first released just a couple of days ago:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete

You may also get some inspiration from there for what you are trying to do. I strongly recommend a Meteor collection-backed implementation rather than trying to cobble together something using existing asynchronous libraries, which is what I've done here. This allows the autocomplete to be completely reactive and client-side (the list contents can update while you're looking at them!) and much quicker.

Some pictures below...

1. Autocompleting users with `@`, where online users are shown in green:

   [image]
2. In the same line, autocompleting something else with metadata and bootstrap icons:

   [image]

Please fork, pull, and improve!