# Meteor 0.6.5.1 and rendered autocomplete using typeahead.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use typeahead.js with Meteor 0.6.5.1 but can't get it to work consistently. `finalItems` is populated on render only after a hot code refresh (and only sometimes at best) but comes up empty once the page is reloaded in the browser. The times that `finalItems` does load properly, typeahead.js works normally.

**HTML**

```
<template name="addProduct">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="styleName">Style Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="ta" name="styleName" class="form-control">
    </div>

</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
Template.addProduct.rendered = function() {
    items = [];
    finalItems = [];

    styles = function() {
        prods = Products.find({}, {
            fields: {
                styleName: 1
            }
        });
        prods.forEach(function(item) {
            items.push(item.styleName);
        });

        finalItems = _.uniq(items);

        console.log(finalItems);

    };

    styles();

    $('#ta').typeahead({
        name: ['styles'],
        local: finalItems
    });

};
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784745/meteor-0-6-5-1-and-twitter-typeahead-js-how-does-it-work (duplicate? without an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

If you're after general free-text autocomplete, you may want to check out my autocomplete package for meteor, first released just a couple of days ago:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete

You may also get some inspiration from there for what you are trying to do. I strongly recommend a Meteor collection-backed implementation rather than trying to cobble together something using existing asynchronous libraries, which is what I've done here.

Autocompleting users with `@`, where online users are shown in green:

[image]

In the same line, autocompleting something else with metadata and bootstrap icons:

[image]

Please fork, pull, and improve!

Answer (score 1):

In meanwhile there is a mrt-package that does the work:

- https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/typeahead
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/meteor-typeahead
- https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead