# Typeahead / Select2 support for Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2, typeahead.js

I'm building a google-style text box that auto-completes typed text.

Using typeahead with [typeahead.js-bootstrap.css](https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#op1').typeahead({
      remote: '/search/%QUERY',
   });
});

<input type="text" id="op1">
```

it **worked** but there are **two problems**:

- I could not customize it. Whenever I make any significant style changes, or use bootstrap's `form-control` class for input element: the text box gets completely messed up.
- The auto-completed ("hint") text was written above the typed text so I whatever color I set  for the hint was the color of the entire text! I tried giving the hint a negative z-order but then it was not displayed at all.

I've tried Typeahead AND Select2 auto-completion libraries with my Bootstrap 3 template, and so far the only thing I was able to work out-of-the-box without completely ruining the layout was the above code

If anyone can solve these problems, or otherwise recommend a full CSS + JS typeahead solution for Bootstrap3, I'd be grateful :)

Comment: Although support has been dropped you can use the "old" plugin see: http://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead. To fix your CSS problems, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059161/css-issue-on-twitter-typeahead-with-bootstrap-3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059161/css-issue-on-twitter-typeahead-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1):

It gives you completely easy way to customise the look with formatresults. You can even write full html view for your results. and to customise the look of input box apply a class to the wrapper for your search box and override select2 rendered css(load the page and check from browser that from where that style is coming).

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

I made a full featured customised search with this.

Comment: I was actually asking how to get it to work **out of the box**. Didn't want to mess with adding my own CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a fork available for select2 that supports Bootstrap 3.

http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/

https://github.com/fk/select2-bootstrap-css#readme